# REGEXP not working for ' (apostrophe) and -(dash) in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm using `REGEXP` for search in a MySQL DB, but it is not returning the proper data when I insert `'` (apostrophe) and `-` (dash) in the search query.

Is there any solution to this?

Here is the full query:

```
select * from table where  (field REGEXP 'SAN DIEGO | SAN DIEGO |^SAN DIEGO' or field2 REGEXP 'SAN DIEGO | SAN DIEGO |^SAN DIEGO' )
```

Comment: Can you tell us the RegExp you're using?

Comment: can't understand what r u trying to say?

Comment: Please give us some examples of strings you want to match.

Comment: like 
----------------------
menu's restaurant,
test'a res

Answer (score 1):

If your REGEXP string delimiters are single quotes, escape them within the string.  Also, depending on your business logic and table structure, you could do a CONCAT to condense the statement:

```
SELECT field1, field2 
WHERE  CONCAT( field1, field2 ) REGEXP 'Mary\'s Restaurant'
```

If you're using a dash within a character class, either escape it or make it the first item in the class, so the engine doesn't think you're trying to specify a range:

```
 ... REGEXP 'Mary\'s[- _]Restaurant'
```

If you're using your San Diego example, you might be able to reduce the REGEXP by using word boundaries:

```
SELECT field1, field2 
WHERE  CONCAT( field1, field2 ) REGEXP '[[:<:]]SAN DIEGO[[:>:]]'
```

See: [MySQL 5.1 REGEXP Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the characters inside square brackets? Try something like this:

```
select * from Table where Field regexp '[\'-]'
```

Comment: can you please explain where i have to put this brackets?
my regexp link this
REGEXP 'text | text |^text'

Comment: @Avinash: Please edit your question to include your entire query.